# How to set up authors in LNCS template?

Tags: hyperref, titles, article, author-number, lncs

I would like to setup the authors and emails in a LNCS paper, but I dont find what is the correct way to do this. I tried this:

```
\author{FirstAuthor LastName, Second Author LastName}
```

The problem is that I tried different ways to set the emails and the institute but the document crashes out. Any idea of how to correctly set this parameters in orther to get something like this:

(*)

```
FirstAuthor LastName, Second Author LastName
    email@email.com      email_2@email.com
                 Institution
```

**Update**

I tried this:

```
\author{FirstAuthor LastName \inst{1} \and SecondAuthor LastName \inst{2}}

%If there are too many authors, use \authorrunning
%\authorrunning{First Author et al.}

\institute{
Insitute 1\\
\email{author1@email.com}\and
Insitute 2\\
\email{author_2@email.com}
}
```

But I dont get (*) style.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: May be  `\author{FirstAuthor LastName \and Second Author LastName}` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Fran, What about the institution and the emails?... I dont get how put them up.

Comment: `\institule{ ... \email{ ....} \and ... \and ...}`. Please read `llncs.doc` that is included in  `llncs2e.zip`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Fran, Could you provide an example?. I all ready read the doc but still dont get how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to authors instructions for Lecture Notes in Computer Science, you must use `\email{<email address>}` within `\institute{}` and therefore you should **not** obtain the style that you are looking for(*).

Compile  `llncs.doc` (in spite of the extension, is really a LaTeX file) with `pfdlatex` to see the instructions for authors.

This is a MWE extracted from `llncs.dem` (also a LaTeX file):

---

[image: MWE]

---

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\begin{document}
\title{Hamiltonian Mechanics unter besonderer Ber\"ucksichtigung derh\"ohreren Lehranstalten}
\author{%
Ivar Ekeland\inst{1}  \and 
Roger Temam\inst{2}
Jeffrey Dean \and 
David Grove \and 
Craig Chambers \and 
Kim~B.~Bruce \and
Elsa Bertino
}%
\institute{
Princeton University, Princeton NJ 08544, USA,\\
\email{I.Ekeland@princeton.edu},\\ 
WWW home page:
\texttt{http://users/\homedir iekeland/web/welcome.html}
\and
Universit\'{e} de Paris-Sud,
Laboratoire d'Analyse Num\'{e}rique, B\^{a}timent 425,\\
F-91405 Orsay Cedex, France}
\maketitle      
\end{document}
```

(*) If you want that style for personal use, then is better start with the standard class `article`:

---

[image: MWE]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\date{}
\def\email#1{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}
\title{Hamiltonian ...}
\author{%
Ivar Ekeland\\ \email{I.Ekeland@princeton.edu}  \and 
Elsa Bertino\\ \email{E.Bertino@princeton.edu}
}%

\maketitle      
\end{document}
```